# Starting a node twice, with differend parameters

Tags: ros, node, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo ,

I want to start my node twice, but it shoud have differend parameter for my COM-Path.
Here is my code:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "dc2412_upsd");
ros::NodeHandle nh1;

  

    ros::param::get("/read_attempt",loop);
    ros::param::get("/com_path", string_var);
    
    
      DC2412 communication(string_var);           //create a objekt 
      pcommunication=&communication;


  ros::ServiceServer service1 = nh1.advertiseService("input_voltage", InputVoltage);
  ros::ServiceServer service2 = nh1.advertiseService("output_voltage", OutputVoltage);
  ros::ServiceServer service3 = nh1.advertiseService("vcap_voltage", VcapVoltage);
  ros::ServiceServer service4 = nh1.advertiseService("set_time_to_shutdown", SetTimeToShutdown);
  ros::ServiceServer service5 = nh1.advertiseService("cap_esr_measurment",CapEsrMeasurment);
  ros::ServiceServer service6 = nh1.advertiseService("cap_esr",CapEsr);
  ros::ServiceServer service7 = nh1.advertiseService("input_current",InputCurrent);
  ros::ServiceServer service8 = nh1.advertiseService("charge_current",ChargeCurrent);    
  ros::Publisher pub1 = nh1.advertise<std_msgs::Int64>("monitorregister",1);
  ros::Publisher pub2 = nh1.advertise<std_msgs::Int64>("chargeregister",1);
```

my launch file:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ros_dc2412_upsd)config/config.yaml" />
     <!--<node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim1" type="turtlesim_node"/>-->

     <group ns="dc1">
          <node pkg="ros_dc2412_upsd" name="sim" type="dc2412_node"/>
     </group>

     <group ns="dc2">
          <node pkg="ros_dc2412_upsd" name="sim" type="dc2412_node"/>
     </group>

</launch>
```

my parameter file:

```
com_path : '/dev/ttyS5'
read_attempt : 10
```

So is it somehow possible? Maybe with the NodeHandle?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388753/starting-a-node-twice,-with-differend-parameters/) by [ros_max](https://answers.ros.org/users/85753/ros_max/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-15**:
An observation:

> ```
>   ros::ServiceServer service1 = nh1.advertiseService("input_voltage", InputVoltage);
> ```

```
  ros::ServiceServer service2 = nh1.advertiseService("output_voltage", OutputVoltage);
  ros::ServiceServer service3 = nh1.advertiseService("vcap_voltage", VcapVoltage);
  ros::ServiceServer service4 = nh1.advertiseService("set_time_to_shutdown", SetTimeToShutdown);
  ros::ServiceServer service5 = nh1.advertiseService("cap_esr_measurment",CapEsrMeasurment);
  ros::ServiceServer service6 = nh1.advertiseService("cap_esr",CapEsr);
  ros::ServiceServer service7 = nh1.advertiseService("input_current",InputCurrent);
  ros::ServiceServer service8 = nh1.advertiseService("charge_current",ChargeCurrent);
```

are these services used to configure the node (ie: set parameters / settings after starting it)?

If they are, perhaps using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that your question is almost a duplicate of #q146486, but I've answered it again, as your title specifically mentions "with different parameters".

---

You have two options:

1. use private parameters: those are relative to the node itself. This is also suggested in #q146486.

   You'd have to move your `rosparam` element and make it a child of each `node` element (so you'd have two of them, loading different parameter files)
2. move the `rosparam` element inside the `group` you've created. So again, you'd create two files, one for each node

In either case, you can't do this:

```
ros::param::get("/read_attempt",loop);
```

as the `/` there makes the parameter name a fully resolved one, which can't be namespaced and will always look at the global parameter space.

Remove the `/` and it would immediately become a relative parameter, which will be resolved against the current 'active' namespace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_max](https://answers.ros.org/users/85753/ros_max/) on 2021-10-15**:
Can you give we some code for the solution.
I dont know how to replace this code:

```
ros::param::get("/read_attempt",loop);
```

so both nodes access different parameters

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-15**:
I'm not sure I understand. The only difference would be removing the `/`:

```
ros::param::get("read_attempt", loop);
```

I would recommend to review [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server), perhaps specifically the section on [private parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Accessing_Private_Parameters). Additionally: [wiki/Names - Graph Resource Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Graph_Resource_Names).

Similar to Windows/Linux/OSX path names, anything starting with a `/` is *absolute*, it cannot be (easily) namespaced, and is always relative to the global root namespace.

Anything without a starting `/` is relative, and will always be looked up relative to the namespace of the node looking for it.

So if you place parameters in the node's namespace, and don't use absolute names, things should just work.

Private parameters are even more 'local': they are only seen by one specific node.